# Should I use a 'URL', 'Path', or other form field type when the field is used to define the location that a file should be saved

Tags: forms, files

I have an administrative form that allows a user to set the save location of a file. I'd imagine that valid locations would be `public://foo`, `private://foo`, and `/foo/bar/foo`. What is the proper form field type to use in this situation, and would this option provide validation or would I have to write it myself?

My initial thought was to use a `path` field, but I'm not really sure how that would handle public/private paths. Would I need to convert those to routes somehow before passing the value through? I guess I'm also not sure if it's even possible to save a file outside of the public/private folders.

Comment: Do you require any kind of special features from that field? For example, autocomplete?

Comment: @IsmailCherri I don't believe so.

Comment: If the save locations are limited, why not use select?

Comment: Options are not limited. It's meant to be a freetext field for the save destination, where foo/bar/etc in the examples above are just placeholders for wildcards.

Comment: I don't think path or url are useful here. You can create your own field implementation where the user will type the path in a text field and will tick a checkbox for private or public. Then later on you can use the value in combination with file_create_url() to get the actual path